# Successful DML operation not getting updated in database

Tags: apex, batch, dml

I am using below code for batch update :

```
List<Database.SaveResult> updateResults;
        updateResults = Database.update(listUserDeactivate, false);
        System.debug('value of users for deactivation after database update :::::'+updateResults);
        for(Integer i=0;i<updateResults.size();i++){
            if (!updateResults.get(i).isSuccess()){
                // DML operation failed
                userDeactSet.add(listUserDeactivate.get(i).Id); 
                system.debug('Failed ID'+listUserDeactivate.get(i).Id);

            }

        }
```

In one batch 200 userids are being processed.I am using parameter "is_all_or_none" as false.So successful records must be processed and will be updated in database.Currently for me successful records are not being processed.While in logs i can see isSuccess()=true for those records.What could be the issue in my code.Or how to restrict database.update with 1 record at a time.

Comment: is there some subsequent exception or rollback?  For example, the `userDeactSet` looks like it gets used elsewhere in the code to do DML

Comment: I got my issue.It was because of another DML operation where i was not using database.update(param,false);

Comment: good job, shall I or you post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was using 2 DML operation I was getting error for 2nd DML where it was not able to process those records which should be updated in database because few other records had some error So i need to use database.update(param,false); instead of normal DML update ;